# prevent menu in layout page in reloading in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a menu in layout page like

```
<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
    <span>Customer</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a href="/Customer/CustomerDetails"> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>View Customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Customer/AddCustomer"> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Add Customer</a></li>                       
  </ul>
</li>

<div class="content">
  @RenderBody()
</div><!-- /.content -->
```

In addcustomer view I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
  $("ul .treeview-menu a").click(function (e) {
    $('#content').load("/Customer/AddCustomer");
  });
});
```

I want to load view without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Which view that you do not want to be displayed?

Comment: Then you need to use javascript/jquery and ajax. But what view, and in response to what client side event?

Comment: i want to dispaly AddCustomer view on clicking on addcustomer @ala

Comment: Then you need to handle the click event of the link, cancel its default action and use ajax to call a serve method and update the DOM with the partial view it returns

Comment: The script needs to be layout page (and you also need to cancel the default redirect using `return false;` after the `.load()` function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should use (.content) instead of (#content)**

Implementing @Stephen answer:

the layout page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
    //Select (AddCustomer) link specifically      
      $("#AddCustomer").click(function (e) {
        $('.content').load("/Customer/AddCustomer");
         return false;
      });
    }); 
</script>

<li class="treeview">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
    <span>Customer</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li><a id="ViewCustomer" href="/Customer/CustomerDetails"> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>View Customer</a></li>
    <li><a id="AddCustomer" href="/Customer/AddCustomer"> <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Add Customer</a></li>                       
  </ul>
</li>

<div class="content">
  @RenderBody()
</div>
```

In addcustomer action method:

```
public ActionResult AddCustomer()
{
    return View("addcustomer");
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer.You should use (.content) instead of (#content)

Comment: their is  one issue that, when i type url name, the partail view is loaded... how can I prevent it??

Answer (score 1):

i have a lot of views so i changed script in the layout page to

```
   $("ul .treeview-menu a").click(function (e) {

        var ulr = $(this).attr("href");
        alert(ulr);
        $('.content').load(ulr);
        return false;
    });
```