# Avoid Refreshing the layout page in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Whenever I click any nav link in Core MVC application the whole layout gets reloaded. This resets the active nav link. Is there any way to load only the @RenderBody() section without reloading the whole page.

I've already been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912814/prevent-menu-in-layout-page-in-reloading-in-mvc/31914767#31914767) answer but I have far too many views to make use of it. Is there any new way to do it in Core MVC.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: _"This resets the active nav link"_ - what does that mean? Anyway, do you mean you want to turn your site into a Single Page Application or something like that, where you refresh the body with partial/API responses?

Comment: Yes, something similar to what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There's no new way I think. But why not save your active nav in RouteData like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411015/5750143